# Java posting JSON to local server not being received by Nodejs Express

Tags: java, json, node.js, express

So I have a json string I'm trying to send to a local server. The code I'm using to post it is:

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build(); //Use this instead 

try {
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://localhost:13000");
    StringEntity params =new StringEntity(jsonCont.toString());
    request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    request.setEntity(params);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
    System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
}catch (Exception ex) {
    // handle exception here
} finally {
    httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
}
```

And then I have a Nodejs server running express to listen for the post:

```
var express = require('express');

var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));

app.post('*', function (request, response) {
    console.log(request);
    response.send("200");
});

app.listen(13000, function () {
    console.log("Started on PORT 13000");
})
```

My issue is that the server is just printing empty json strings (e.g {}), and not the json string I sent it. (The Java code is returning 200 success)

I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong here, but what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are posting `json`, you should use json middleware for body-parser

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `bodyParser.json()` instead of `bodyParser.urlencoded()`.